# How to add a postfix to a docker container name if a given name already exist?

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

Is it possible to add a postfix to a container name if, for any reason, that container name is already in use?

For instance, a syntax I can add to the following `NAME` which adds auto-generated numbers to avoid collision.

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  my_service:
    container_name: NAME
```

Comment: I don't believe this is supported by docker-compose. You could possibly populate an environmental variable and use that value as a prepend assuming you're willing to populate a random string as an environmental variable and hope it doesn't still conflict.

Comment: You almost never need to manually specify `container_name`.  Docker Compose should create a name for you that’s unambiguous.

Comment: I specify names for variety of reasons, e.g., to avoid the hard-to-read-auto-generated names.